# Android Source Code for android:text attribute processing?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-source

I am trying to find the original android source code, where the android:text attribute from the layout files is resolved to the actual string referred to via @string/ (for instance: android:text="@string/hello"). The reason is the following: I have created a completely different way of setting up my layouts using a custom XML which in turn uses pre-written Widgets, an example:

```
<dialog name="Homepage">
  <field type="Combobox" label="Enter">
</dialog>
```

What I want to do: I want to be able to change the label attribute in my example to: label="@string/enter" - so I can make use of the localization feature in android.

But in order to handle those @string commands, I need to know, where this is done in the original Android Source Code (on version 2.3 for instance) so I can imitate the behaviour. So far the only way I know of to obtain string resources is to use context.getString(int resID) - trouble is, how would I go about translating the String "@string/enter" to a res id? I assume I can't, which is why i am curious about how android handles this.

I'd be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction and I hope my explanation wasn't too confusing :) .

Comment: P.s. Again I forgot (and cant prepend) the opening line: Hello everyone :)

Comment: No problem about that opening line. It's actually better not to use a signature and opening line on SO for the reasons stated in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/167991). So not posting one is fully ok and definitely not considered rude around here. :)

Comment: @alextrsc: Thanks for the answer - which also cleared up my question, as to why I cant add a salutation :) - I'll keep this in mind for the future - thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [..] trouble is, how would I go about translating the String "@string/enter" to a res id?

You can use [`Resources.getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for that.

Small sample that gets the res id of `@string/enter`:

```
Resources r = getResources();
int resId = r.getIdentifier("enter", "string", getPackageName());
```

Given that the format for resources is always the same, you can parse all three arguments out of this string and fill them into `getIdentifier()`:

```
@[<package_name>:]<resource_type>/<resource_name>
```

*from [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml)*

Comment: Wow, thank you for this easily understandable and concise answer :)!

Comment: Mhhh I tried out your suggestion, but somehow it does not find the string resource (getIdentifier(...) returns 0, i.e. invalid resource), although I made sure it exists - any suggestions?

Comment: Ok - Fixed the problem: The package name must not be null, when I passed the correct package name (accessible via context.getPackageName()) it found the string resource.

Comment: @Zainodis Oh sorry, wrote that down from the top of my head. You're right. Thanks for fixing my answer. :)